# How do I create a systemd service for a continuously running application (only in a time window)

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, systemd-timer

I have a software that basically continuously analyze a camera stream and send some information to a server, this is a headless system (Ubuntu 16.04). The application must be started every day (except Sunday) at 7:30am and stopped at 10pm. This application must run at any time only in that time-window, so must be restarted in case of crash and in case of power loss (the computer hosting the software is set to poweron after power loss), but only if we are in the time-window.
Currently I'm using these cronjobs

```
* 7-21 * * 1-6 check-software.sh 
00 22 * * 1-6 killall mysoftware
```

Where check-software.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_process() {
if ps aux | grep "[m]ysoftware"
then
    return 1
else 
    return 0
fi
}

check_process   
if (test $? -eq 0)
then
    echo mysoftware not running 
    ./mysoftware
else
    echo mysoftware running
fi
```

It works fine, but I'd like to use a systemd service instead of cron..so I tried to use a service together with a timer in this way.

`myservice.service` in `.config/systemd/user`

```
[Unit]
Description=My Software
StartLimitInterval=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
WorkingDirectory=/opt/mysoftware
ExecStart=/opt/mysoftware/mysoftware
ExecStartPost=/home/myuser/clear_timer.sh
```

`mytimer.timer` in `.config/systemd/user`

```
[Unit]
Description=Run my software

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon-Sat 07:29:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

`clear_timer.sh` is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm ~/.local/share/systemd/timers/*
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
systemctl --user restart mytimer.timer
```

In my mind clear_timer should do the trick, removing the last-execution of timer so when there is a powerloss, if 7:30 is passed, the timer realize that it never triggered before and triggers. However this doesn't work! If there is a powerloss after 7:30 the software is not launched, otherwise this approach works as expected (but I always need a cronjob to stop the software at 10pm). Any idea?